# Converting a row of dataframe to vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I researched my problem across the web to no avail. Basically, I have a `dataframe` with columns of mixed data types.

```
ID Email SSN
 1   A    3
 .   .    .
 .   .    .
```

I would like a `vector` of that row in `list` form. I have tried using `unlist` but it's returning the following result:

```
Email   SSN Phone 
    2     1     1
```

How can I get `R` to return `c(1, A, 3)` instead?

Comment: You can't get a vector or a matrix with different data type, so you'll get only character values in the vector.
`as.vector(t(df[1,]))` is the command to extract the first row and transpose it.

Comment: What is the purpose, what is the next step? If you could give us more background, maybe there is no need to do this at all. You could try `as.character(df1[1, ])`

Comment: @hannes101 ^ I love you. I wish I would have asked this question 3 hours ago.... --;

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(ID=c("Alex", "Billy"), Email=c("a@b.com","c@d.com"), SSN=c(2,3))
#     ID   Email SSN
#1  Alex a@b.com   2
#2 Billy c@d.com   3
df <- data.frame(ID=c("Alex", "Billy"), Email=c("a@b.com","c@d.com"), SSN=c(2,3))
df[2,]
#     ID   Email SSN
# 2 Billy c@d.com   3
 as.vector(df[2,])
#      ID   Email SSN
# 2 Billy c@d.com   3
```

Comment: Check the class of `as.vector(df[2,])`.  The result is either a list or data.frame (a generalized vector), not an atomic vector.

Comment: I understand your point. The OP's question is rather blurring on whether s/he wants an object that behaves as vector that s/he can process (it seemed to me as if so) or s/he really wants R's vector type (aside from implicit coercings 1 to "1" etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Vectors in R cannot be mixed type - i.e., they cannot contain strings and numerics.  The best you can do is get `c("1", "A", "3")` because R will convert to the most general.  To get that, run:

```
unlist(df[1,])
```

Notice that you are likely getting an integer with `email` in your example because of the infamous `stringsAsFactors` argument:

```
df = data.frame(id = 3, email = "a", phone = 3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
unlist(df[1,])
```

Comment: Why the unlist? I mean just selecting the row should be sufficient.

Comment: I understood the question to request an atomic vector, not a generalized vector like a list or data.frame.  If "vector" includes generalized vectors like lists, then I agree with you, the `unlist` would be unnecessary.

Comment: Ah, the `t()` in my comment transformed it also into a vector, so I didn't see it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the classes of the row elements, you can use `as.list()`:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,2),
                 var2 = c("A", "B"),
                 var3 = c(3,4), stringsAsFactors = F)

  var1 var2 var3
1    1    A    3
2    2    B    4

row1 <- as.list(df[1,])

$var1
[1] 1

$var2
[1] "A"

$var3
[1] 3

> sapply(row1, class)
       var1        var2        var3 
  "numeric" "character"   "numeric"
```

Transposing this list will give you a 1x3 matrix with the correct classes:

```
> t(row1)
     var1 var2 var3
[1,] 1    "A"  3
```

Comment: `class(t(as.list(df[1,]))) # matrix`. And `is.vector(t(as.list(df[1,])))  # FALSE`. So, I am of the opinion that the OP really could not distinguish btw "an object behaving like a vector" and "a really R vector type object". It seems his sole object is to subsetting the dataframe accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, the question was not worded very clearly. As he said `I would like a vector of that row in list form`, I thought he may be fine using a `list`.